# How do I perform google authentication with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have read many stackoverflow responses about this, but they seem very outdated. In order to do end to end testing on my application, I need to login through google SSO which is the login method the application uses. How can I perform this task with selenium because I keep getting the following. [image: Google Rejection]

Comment: how can I leverage the chrome driver? am I suppose to be using browserstack or something to help me?

Comment: Please post the code what you tried?